# Verify Site key and secret key is correct in recapcha

Tags: php, recaptcha

Hi currently i have implemented [recaptcha v2](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/display) in my php website and everything is working fine. I have added 2 text box where I can insert site key and secret key. **But the problem is even the keys are wrong still recaptcha is showing and for wrong keys recaptcha v2 always fail.**

1. So I want to know, how can I verify site key and secret key of a
   website is correct or not via code ?
2. Also is there any way I can know the recaptcha is working or not via
   code ?

I have read this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/display)  but there is no ReCaptchaResponse for site key and secret key is wrong .

> Example of wrong keys

**Actual keys**

**Site Key**: 7LeAbKcdAAAAAOezcfoFK-tekV_H2V0IzTy5rUn-

**secret Key**: 7LeAbKcdAAAAAMfyCxR7teg5VzB1Am**5**Q1jk_I6Tb

***Wrong keys***

**Site Key**: 7LeAbKcdAAAAAOezcfoFK-tekV_H2V0IzTy5rUn-

**secret Key**: 7LeAbKcdAAAAAMfyCxR7teg5VzB1Am**6**Q1jk_I6Tb

Here in wrong keys, i just changed one number but still the recaptcha keep showing . Actually if the site key and secret key is wrong then it should not display.

> I have seen this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33620692/how-to-detect-if-a-re-captcha-site-key-is-valid-via-javascript#answer-66072292) and it is very helpful. But for my case
> even if both site key and secret key is correct i am getting **ERROR
> for site owner: Invalid domain for site key**

Please help to find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Google does not provide methods to verify site keys or secret keys. You should make sure your secret key and the site key match each other before entering.

Comment: Thank you . I think so. But if i make a solution where user need to enter their site key and secret key and if they enter wrong key i need to notify that your keys are in correct.  I am looking for a solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

There's an answer to this where we can verify the recaptcha on the server side (https://stackoverflow.com/a/27439796/7275579)

```
<?php
    $captcha;

    if(isset($_POST['g-recaptcha-response']))
        $captcha=$_POST['g-recaptcha-response'];

    if(!$captcha){
        echo '<h2>Please check the the captcha form.</h2>';
        exit;
    }

    $response = json_decode(file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=SECRET_KEY&response=".$captcha."&remoteip=".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']), true);

    if($response['success'] == false)
    {
        echo 'Invalid';
    }
    else
    {
        // Proceed
    }
```

Also make sure to encode the captcha using `urlencode`